# SVN : Get/Checkout the file with log in single request

Tags: apache, svn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn, apache-modules

We have used VisualSVN Server 2.5.8 in windows 2008 machine. The requirement is we need to provide the commit comments into starting of the file for every get/checkout request. We don't want to append commit comments into file while committing the file.

Is there any way to get or checkout the file with the log(commit comments).

Thanks in advance.